# Finally block excecution

Tags: java, block, finally

When the below method is called it's printing output as 6 but I am expecting output as 5 as I have re-assigned n = 5 in the `finally` block.

Can anybody please help me with this?

```
public static int p() {
    int n = 0;
    try {
        n = 6 ;
        return n;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return n;
    } finally {
        n = 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: But you already returned 6.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be answered by understanding the order of execution of your code. In your scenario you will always be returning the value of `n` before you hit the final block, in your code you will always be returning the value of `6`. You will never return `5` (Final Block) or `0` (Catch Block).

**So why would you never get `0`?**

You would never get `0` because the code within the `try` part of your `try-catch-final` statement will never in a million years throw any exception the way it has been written, so the `catch` statement is redundant.

**So why would you never get `5`?**

You would never get `5` because the order of execution is `return` statement in the `try` block is executed first and then the final block runs. A `try-final` statement is the only statement I can think of (Happy to be proven wrong in comments) that any code is executed after a return statement is executed.

There is no reason why in your scenario you would have that final block unless for whatever reason you didn't trust the Garbage Collector was doing it's job, in which case you would `nullify` the `n` property here and that's it.

Your code could easily be re-written as the below because `6` is the only value your code will ever return.

```
public static int p() {
    return 6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by `luk2302` you are already return the value as 6. If you want to return the value as 5 then change your method as shown below.

```
public static int p() {
    int n = 0;
    try {
      n = 6;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return n;
    } finally {
      n = 5;
    }
    return n;
  }
```

Comment: before return statement only finally block will execute right? then n should be initialized to 5 know?

Comment: @YallalingKolkur no, finally runs after the return statement in your code (not in this answer's code)

Comment: @YallalingKolkur n is not visible from outside your method. So you are returning 6 and afterwards assigning a new value of 5 to n. This value will not be returned to the caller of the method.

Answer (score -3):

Question is very interesting, i even surprised why it is happening like that. When i checked about finally block i got the definition like below

"Java finally block is a block used to execute important code such as closing the connection, etc. Java finally block is always executed whether an exception is handled or not. Therefore, it contains all the necessary statements that need to be printed regardless of the exception occurs or not."

But i have compiled your program and saw how the compiled class looks like. It gives the answer

## Original Java class

```
public class Finally {

    public static int p() {
        int n = 0;
        try {
            n = 6 ;
            return n;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return n;
        } finally {
            n = 5;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = p();
        System.out.println("value of n " + n);

    }
}
```

## Compiled class

```
public class Finally {
    public Finally() {
    }

    public static int p() {
        byte n = 0;

        byte var2;
        try {
            n = 6;
            byte var1 = n;
            return var1;
        } catch (Exception var6) {
            var2 = n;
        } finally {
            boolean var8 = true;
        }

        return var2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = p();
        System.out.println("value of n " + n);
    }
}
```

As you can see how return statements translated due to that we don't see the value which is assigned in finally block instead we see value which is assigned in the try block.

Hope that clarify your answer.

Comment: No need to compile the class, it is obvious from the original java code that a reassignment of `n` after the return does not affect the returned value. And there is nothing surprising about it.

Comment: Why does this surprise you? It's understanding the order of execution, in this case `return` will always be executed before the final block. In this scenario there is no reason to have the final block unless you didn't trust that `n` would be Garbage Collected at which point you would use it to set `n` to `null`.